# Align rows in Pandas DataFrame at each column's maximum

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way to align rows of a Pandas DataFrame at a specific condition for each column such as the maximum?

Here is my example where I manually shift the columns after finding each column's maximum but I'm hoping there is an easier and more efficient way.

```
tmp = yearly_data_scaled.filter(regex="ZW")  # DataFrame to align
tmp.describe()
```

> ```
>           ZW_2013     ZW_2014     ZW_2015     ZW_2016     ZW_2017
> count  251.000000  251.000000  251.000000  251.000000  247.000000
> mean     0.864789    0.803246    0.825631    0.843604    0.806205
> std      0.053225    0.090301    0.047080    0.068289    0.049530
> min      0.758926    0.647762    0.736072    0.701984    0.716466
> 25%      0.821169    0.734540    0.795039    0.783745    0.779140
> 50%      0.866351    0.791254    0.818219    0.831156    0.794635
> 75%      0.891943    0.866758    0.847499    0.904693    0.819380
> max      1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
> ```

Plot before alignment:

```
_ = tmp.plot(figsize=(20, 15))
```

> [image: Before Alignment]

Find the maximums of each column:

```
max_list = []
for i in range(num_years):
    max_idx = tmp['ZW_' + str(start_year + i)].idxmax()
    max_list.append(max_idx)
print('Index of the maximum for each column = ' + str(max_list) + '\n')
```

> ```
> Index of the maximum for each column = [12, 85, 123, 108, 126]
> ```

Manually shift each column so they align at index 125 (approximately at the horizontal center of the graph) and Plot:

```
_ = pd.concat([tmp['ZW_2013'].shift(125-max_list[0]),
               tmp['ZW_2014'].shift(125-max_list[1]),
               tmp['ZW_2015'].shift(125-max_list[2]),
               tmp['ZW_2016'].shift(125-max_list[3]),
               tmp['ZW_2017'].shift(125-max_list[4])], axis=1).plot(figsize=(20, 15))
```

> [image]

Comment: You can consider using for loop as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [`Dataframe.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
new_tmp = tmp.filter(regex="ZW").apply(lambda col: col.shift(125 - col.idxmax()))

print(new_tmp.equals(_))
# True
```

Comment: As of now, I can't think of a better answer that is worth the effort.  Great answer !

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @piRSquared ... I somehow impressed a pandas guru? No doubt I was just first to answer. Happy holidays!

Comment: @JohnCotter ... you are welcome. Glad to help! Happy coding!